# Can't build project, Gradle output tells Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, build

I've just opened my project and I couldn't build it.
Here is my Gradle console output:

```
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
18:12:07.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

Everything worked well when I worked on it yesterda. What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: start internet connection on your pc and `clean` and then `Rebuild` the project, I have the same one it ll work like this

Comment: I just copied my whole project into a new one and it solved the problem.
Thanks anyways!

Comment: For anyone else who has run into this problem, this answer has the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70621318/185034

Answer (score 0):

What JSON file is giving the error? The file might have been corrupted.

If it is the JSON file provided by `Firebase` or `Crashlytics` or some other library, you can re-download and replace the file after cleaning your project..

Answer (score -1):

In all seriousness, use Maven - Gradle is not backwards compatible with itself.  Gradle developers do not understand that they have a contract with developers and vX is always breaking vX-1 or, if you must use Gradle, then use v5.6.4