# gradle error - Could not parse module metadata

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, build

Facing this issue while adapting gradle 7.2, the spring-rabbit-2.4.4.module is present in repo but still im getting error, could somone please help

Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.4.
> Required by:
> project : > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp:3.1.0 > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit:3.2.2 > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:3.2.2 > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:2.6.7
> > Could not resolve org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.4.
> > Could not parse module metadata https://nexus.btsint.com/nexus/Hercules/org/springframework/amqp/spring-rabbit/2.4.4/spring-rabbit-2.4.4.module
> > Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 15 column 1 path $
> > Could not resolve org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.4.
> > Could not parse module metadata https://nexus.btsint.com/nexus/repositories/herculesint-group/org/springframework/amqp/spring-rabbit/2.4.4/spring-rabbit-2.4.4.module
> > Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 15 column 1 path $
> > Could not resolve org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.4.
> > Could not parse module metadata https://nexus.btsint.com/nexus/dynamite-maven2-group/org/springframework/amqp/spring-rabbit/2.4.4/spring-rabbit-2.4.4.module
> > Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 15 column 1 path $
> Could not resolve org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.4.
> Required by:
> project : > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp:3.1.0 > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit:3.2.2 > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:3.2.2 > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core:3.2.2 > org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp:5.5.11
> > Could not resolve org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.4.
> > Could not parse module metadata https://nexus.btsint.com/nexus/hercules/org/springframework/amqp/spring-rabbit/2.4.4/spring-rabbit-2.4.4.module
> > Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 15 column 1 path $
> > Could not resolve org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.4.
> > Could not parse module metadata https://nexus.btsint.com/nexus/repositories/herculesint-group/org/springframework/amqp/spring-rabbit/2.4.4/spring-rabbit-2.4.4.module
> > Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 15 column 1 path $
> > Could not resolve org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.4.
> > Could not parse module metadata https://nexus.btsint.com/nexus/dynamite-maven2-group/org/springframework/amqp/spring-rabbit/2.4.4/spring-rabbit-2.4.4.module
> > Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 15 column 1 path $

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: For anyone else who has run into this problem, this answer has the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70621318/185034